# flutter_html image src tag in single quote

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_html in my flutter project using Android Studio. I have an issue in displaying the html code for the image tag(I got the html content from an xml), where the src is in single quote:

```
<a class='article-gallery__image-container' href='https://xxxxx/xxx.jpg'> 
<img alt="xxxx" src='https://xxxxx/xxxx.jpg' class='article-gallery__image' title="xxxxx" /></a>
```

I have another article content extracted from xml where the image src tag is in double quote, the image can be shown:

```
<img width="500" src="https://xxxx/xxxx.jpg" />
```

If the src tag is in single quote, the image cannot be shown, however if the image src tag is in double quote, the image can be shown, how could I fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter_html is still adding more tags and enhancement, not every tag is supported in flutter_html.

Regarding your problem actually you can replace the single quote with the double quote

```
    s.replaceAll("'", "\"");
```

but pls be sure it doesn't effect any other tags.

or if the all image is in jpg then replace like this

```
s.replaceAll("jpg'", "jpg\"").replaceAll("''http", "\"'http");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, after I implemented your solution, then I found that the problem was actually from my original html source code extracted from xml. Not sure why it auto makes all my single tags ='...' to =\'....\'

and your .replaceAll helps me solve this. Thanks a lot.